# Не появляется модальное окно

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

Модальное онко на JS, CSS и HTML не появляется.

HTML файл:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>мода</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleses.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

   <img src = "catara1.jpg" class = "catara1_class" id = "open-modal">

   <div id = "modal1" class  = "modal">
    <div class = "modal_content">
     <span class = "modal_close">&times;</span>
     <img class = "catara2_class" src="catara2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>


   <script src = "cotick\kava.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

CSS файл:

```
.catara1_class 
{
 display: block;

 height: auto;
 min-height: 100px;
 max-height: 500px;
 width: auto;
 min-width: 50px;
 max-width: 250px;
}

.modal 
{
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;

 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;

 overflow: auto;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}

.modal_active 
{
 display: block;
}

.modal_content
{
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 2rem;
 border: 1px solid darkgray;
 margin: 15% auto 0;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px black;

 position: relative;
 animation-name: animatetop;
 animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


.modal_close 
{
 color: darkgray;
 float: right;

 font-size: 28px;
 font-weight: bold;

}

.modal_close:hover, 
.modal_close:focus 
{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor:pointer;

}

 @keyframes animatetop 
 {
  from 
  {
   top: -300px;
   opacity: 0;
  }

  to 
  {
   top: 0;
   opacity: 1
   
  }

 }
```

JS :

```
const btn = document.getElementById('open-modal');
const modal = document.getElementById('modal1');

const closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('modal_close');

btn.onclick = () => 
{

  modal.classList.add(".modal_active");
  modal.addEventListener('click', hideModal);

  closeBtn.classList.add('.modal_close');
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

  function closeModal() 
  {
    modal.classList.remove(".modal_active");
    closeBtn.removeEventListener("click", closeModal);
  }

  function hideModal(event) 
  {
    if (event.target == modal) 
    {
        closeModal;
    }
  }
};
```

Идея, при нажатии на изображение должно появлятся модальное окно с функцией закрытия на "пустое" место или на крестик справа вверху.

Comment: А в консоли что пишет, или там ничего?

Comment: @dresser GET file:///D:/workspaceVsCode/cotick/cotick/kava.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: ```modal.classList.add(".modal_active")``` без точки вот так -  ```modal.classList.add("modal_active");```

Comment: @dresser да, только что заметил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<img href='/path' class="catara1_class" id = "open-modal" />

   <div id = "modal1" class  = "modal">
    <div class = "modal_content">
     <span class = "modal_close">&times;</span>
     <img class = "catara2_class" src="catara2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('open-modal');
const modal = document.getElementById('modal1');

const closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('modal_close');

btn.onclick = () => 
{
  modal.classList.add("modal_active");
  modal.addEventListener('click', hideModal);

  closeBtn.classList.add('modal_close');
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

  function closeModal() 
  {
    modal.classList.remove("modal_active");
    closeBtn.removeEventListener("click", closeModal);
  }

  function hideModal(event) 
  {
  console.log(event.target)
    if (event.target.className == "modal") 
    {
        closeModal();
    }
  }
};
```